# Importing code into xlsb vs xlsm

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have vbscript code that imports a cls and bas file into an excel file and then runs a function to do some refreshes of data from a server.

```
book.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "D:\Energy\Data\ProfileAutomation.cls"
XL.Application.Run("'" + wkname + "'!Run")
```

When the Excel file is an xlsm it works great. When the excel file is an xlsb it doesn't work. It gives me an error when it tries to run the code and the error is:

```
Can't perform operation since the project is protected
```

Now there is a protected add-in that is needed for this refresh that already exists in the workbooks, and it's protected if the file is an xlsm or xlsb. **Does anyone know why this would make a difference in my injected code?**

Comment: Where are you assigning `book`?  Might help to show a little more of your code.

Comment: The problem is the exact same code works with xlsm but doesn't with xlsb so I can show the code but I guess I didn't see the point since it works with xlsm just fine. Was thinking there must be something special with xlsb format that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I don't have any problem running your code  on an xlsb-formatted file.